# Performant dragging / resizing / rotating between nested SVG coordinate systems

Tags: javascript, performance, svg, coordinate-transformation

An app I'm working on has a hierarchy of nested SVG boxes that the user can manipulate with the mouse, and I'm trying to find the most efficient and/or maintainable way to keep track of the relative coordinate systems involved, convert between them when necessary, etc.

The intended interface is intuitive. I'll explicitly list the requirements:

1. Boxes can be moved, rotated and resized with the mouse.
2. When resizing, moving or rotating a box, its children fluidly move and rotate with it.
3. Boxes can be dropped into new parents.
4. Some line segments will cross between boundaries.
5. The mouse-event coordinates will have to synchronize fluidly with whatever local coordinate space it's working with.

**[Main question]** It seems to me this kind of interaction is desirable for many types of apps. Surely, I'm not the first person trying this. But I can't find a good library or set of best practices. The closest I've come across is [interact.js](http://interactjs.io), but it has turned out to be too incomplete and inflexible. Is there anything else out there?

**[Sub-question]** In case there's not a good library out there, I'm considering at least two approaches: *(i)* Have only one coordinate space, and calculate the coordinates of specific boxes recursively by having them consult their parents and then apply their local transformations. *(ii)* Use `transform` on the containing `<g>` of each box, so we get a hierarchy of nested coordinate spaces. The latter seems to be more maintainable, but could the former be more performant? Thoughts welcome.

Comment: Asking for library recommendations will get your question closed as off topic. Perhaps you'd like to rewrite it to avoid such an outcome.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Thanks for the warning, but I did not ask for library recommendations. Really, what I need is the direction and insight of someone who's been through this exercise, so as not to duplicate their effort, though a useful answer might include a reference to an existing library. ----- Anyway, I asked the question I meant to ask, and I think the answer could be useful to many. If they'd like to close my question despite that, so be it.

Comment: Been there, done that. Take a look at: http://svgdiscovery.com/E1/E1a.htm

Comment: @FrancisHemsher: Looks useful. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertLongson: I don't want you to close it. But if you believe closing it is in the best interest of SO, you should definitely do it.